# What are the stats of the Razer green/black color crystal?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I have seen the green/black saber crystals from the Razer peripheral promotion, and I was wondering what the stats are. Are they like the yellow/black color crystal? Can you improve its stats, or are we stuck with low stats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, there was only [this item](http://www.torhead.com/item/93jY9fO/se-black-green-color-crystal), which is +4 endurance, exactly like the original pre-order crystals.

However, it seems that Bioware has now added a pre-order vendor who sells high-level versions of the yellow-black crystal. It's possible they might do the same for the Razr crystals in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As of Patch 1.2 you can trade in the original +4 endurance crystal and 250,000 credits for one of these level 50 crystals:

- SE Black Green Eviscerating Crystal — +41 Critical Rating
- SE Black Green Hawkeye Crystal — +41 Power
- SE Black Green Indestructible Crystal — +41 Endurance
- SE Black Green War Hero's Crystal — +41 Expertise Rating

You get them from the Mods vendors on Coruscant and Dromund Kaas near the Market kiosks.  The SE versions are slightly lighter/yellower in color than the Rakghoul Outbreak event crystals:

[image]

You could also get four cheaper +16 level 31 black/green crystals from that event.